# Should i store data that i fetch from third party databse

Tags: node.js

I have an API that fetch airplane schedule from third party databases. When the frontend show the data that the API fetch from the database, should the application take data from local database or take the data from the third party?

Answer (score 0):

I am considering this data as dynamic in nature and pretty critical too ( airplane schedule).
I am also assuming that you are aggregating this data from a number of providers and you must have transformed this data into a generic structure ( a common format across all providers).

In my opinion, you should save it into a local database, with a timestamp which indicates when the data was refreshed last.
Ideally you should display the last refreshed info against each provider ( OR airline) in your site. Also you could run a scheduler to refresh the data in regular intervals.

It would be nice to show that next refresh is at "nn" minutes. ( with a count down ).

If you can afford to, you can let the user refresh the data, but it is risky if the concurrent users are considerably more in number.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my opinion.

If the API data/record is not subject to change then saving it to local database can be a good idea.

Users will fetch the data from the local database and for updating this local database, you can create another program (run in server) to update/fetch the data from API. This way only limited connection is requesting to API.